# apply a function on each elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to apply a function to each element of a list. I want to avoid for loop here.

I have list of path names as output from tar.getnames(). I want to get list of filenames. Below is what I tried but I am getting error.

```
map(os.path.basename(), tar.getnames())
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 map(os.path.basename(), tar.getnames())

TypeError: basename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to the function `os.path.basename` and not what the function `os.path.basename` returns when called without arguments `()`:
Use `map(os.path.basename, tar.getnames())`.

Comment: path_list
path_list=['folder/file1.csv','folder/file2.csv']
map(os.path.basename, path_list)
<map at 0x7f6c00616730>

Comment: I only get memory reference and not the list of files [file1.csv,file2.csv]:)

Comment: Lazy execution, look at `list(map(os.path.basename, tar.getnames()))`.